# Meaning of the words "Recitativo" and "tutte le corde" in music?

Tags: theory, beethoven, keyboard-pedals, romantic-period, opera

I am trying to understand Romantic music. I came across this extract from **Beethoven's Piano Sonata op.110** from the **Allegro man non troppo** part.

[image]

I want to understand what the words *"Recitativo" and "tutte le corde"* mean? The internet explained *"recitativo"* as recitative, and I couldn't find the meaning for *"tutte le corde"*. Examples to understand these terms would help.

Answer (score 4):

Tutte Le Corde tells you to release the left pedal. The earlier marking Una Corda tells you to press down the left pedal. The left pedal is sometimes called the “soft” pedal. It makes the sound softer by shifting the piano hammers so they only strike one string at a time (hence Una Corda, which is Italian for “one string”). Tutta Le Corde is Italian for “all the strings”, which you achieve by lifting the left pedal.

Comment: The mechanism of the left pedal on upright pianos is apparently that it puts a screen between the hammers and the strings instead of shifting the hammers.

Comment: @Dekkadeci in my experience, the more common mechanism on uprights is a bar behind the hammers, on which they rest, which is moved closer to the strings when the left pedal is used, so the hammers have less room to accelerate and therefore strike the strings with a lower velocity.

Answer (score 2):

From the ever-reliable Dolmetsch page, which really ought to be where every question submitted here should redirect :-=) ,

> recitative can be: recitativo secco or recativo parlante  literally
>   'dry' (seco) or 'spoken' (parlante    with only a very simple chordal
>   accompaniment
>   this is a rapid dialogue which carries forward the plot,
>   particularly in comic operas
>
> recitativo accompagnato recitativo stromentato
>     literally 'accompanied' with the active involvement of the
>   orchestra used to accompany more emphatic phrases such as the
>   declamatory introduction to an aria